# Update ListView Item TextView

Tags: android, listview

I am unable to update TextView item on ListView row.

```
        @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        row=convertView;
        if(row==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_lineup_single, parent, false);
        }
```

.

```
            ibCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                strArtistClicked = ls_Artist.get(position);
                accessWebService_GetDBData_FollowUnfollow();

                strArtistCheckbox = ls_FollowingValue.get(position);

                if (strArtistCheckbox.equals("1")){

                    ls_FollowingValue.set(position, "0");
                    ibCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkbox_empty);

                    //View followersCountUpdate = lv.getChildAt(position);
                    View followersCountUpdate = lv.getAdapter().getView(position, null, lv);

                    tvArtistFollowersCount = followersCountUpdate.findViewById(R.id.tvArtistFollowersCount);

                    int FollowingCount = Integer.parseInt(tvArtistFollowersCount.getText().toString());
                    String f = String.valueOf(FollowingCount-1);
                    tvArtistFollowersCount.setText(f);
```

TextView updates with this code BUT only for visible items:

```
View followersCountUpdate = lv.getChildAt(position);
```

So I use this code instead to access invisible listview items:

```
View followersCountUpdate = lv.getAdapter().getView(position, null, lv);
```

This line is where I do the textview update but it doesn't update text:

```
tvArtistFollowersCount.setText(f);
```

Additional Info (Printing View Logs)

```
lv.getChildAt(position));
getView: 01: android.widget.LinearLayout{3bb40c4 VFE...C.. .......D 0,0-1080,210 #7f07009c app:id/ll_main}

lv.getAdapter().getView(position, null, lv))
getView: 02: android.widget.LinearLayout{4a78ee2 VFE...C.. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f07009c app:id/ll_main}
```

Comment: I think **position** is messed up. Position for getView() refers to data list while position for getChildAt() refers to visible item views. Example, list of 100 items and scrolled up 10 items, now the first item view is getChildAt(0) which is populated by getView() of the 11th data item. If possible, update question with complete getView().

Comment: Instead of trying to update the TextView from ListVIew item I get the text value from index of my List Array, change it, and replace old value with new value in array, works perfect.

1. ls_ArtistFollowersTotalCount.get(position)  
2. Do calculations for the new value and setText(MY_NEW_VALUE)
3. Important: replace old value with new value in array: ls_ArtistFollowersTotalCount.set(position, MY_NEW_VALUE);